# I cannot change the title property of the styleSheets object. Why?

Tags: javascript

Is the `title` property of the `styleSheets` object read-only? Why is it that I cannot change it?

```js
alert(document.styleSheets[0].title);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js-practice.css" type="text/css" title="first">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="secondcss.css" type="text/css" title="second">
```

(Not a Stack Snippet because the stylesheets wouldn't actually be linked, so it would be misleading.) Using the `title` property, I can read the `title`, but when I try to change it, it doesn't change.

```js
document.styleSheets[0].title = "newfirst";
```

This does not work.

I tried using internal CSS, and the result was the same.

```js
alert(document.styleSheets[0].title);
```

```html
<style title="first">
body {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

I can only read the `title` property, but when I try to change it, it doesn't work.

However, what does work is when I target the `link` elements instead.

```js
var stylesheets2 = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

stylesheets2[0].title = "newtitle";
alert(document.styleSheets[0].title);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js-practice.css" type="text/css title="first">
```

This does work, which leads me to my second question - what is the connection between the `link` element, and the `styleSheets` object? I think the reason why I can change the `title` when targeting the `Link` element directly is because I am not changing the `Title` property of the `styleSheets` object, but the html attribute of that element.

Comment: What purpose does `title` serve here that it's important to you to change it? Where/how is a `link rel="stylesheet"` element's `title` ever used?

Comment: Well, the JS book I'm reading gave this exercise as an example where you have 3 stylesheets with tittles, and you use prompt to enter your stylesheet name (title), and if it matches any of the existing stylesheets, it picks it, if not, it tells you that it doesn't exist. So, I was just trying to replicate it. Basically the idea is to see if a certain stylesheet exists, and they use title as a way to select them. However, they have used the `styleSheets` object, not the `link` element title attribute. They used internal `styles`, not external too.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you mind explaining what is the connection between the `link` element, and the `stylesheets` object? And I have two more related questions. 1. About the Length of the stylesheets. They differ depending on how disables them, and who measures them. If you store the `link` elements in a variable, and then disable one of them, the variable will tell you that the same length is the same, but the `stylesheets.length` will tell that there are 1 less stylesheets. I don't understand why? It must have something to do with the relationship between the `link` and the object.

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling" a stylesheet?

Comment: And the second question that I have is, when you have 3 links. If all of them have a `title`. The first one 
 is going to get selected automatically. If you remove the `title` from the 2nd or 3rd, the one without the `title`
 gets selected, however, if you only remove the `title` from the 1st one, while the other two still 
 have them, then the second one gets chosen, not the first one. Why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean to disable it like this: document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When you disable a styleSheet, you can't select it, and the browser does not choose it automatically. Like if you have 3 stylesheets, the last one will get automatically selected, but if you disable it, the previous one gets selected.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know about the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) property on stylesheets. I think you'll need to post each of those as its own question, with exactly the code showing what you're doing and what you're asking about. (I haven't gotten deep into manipulating stylesheets, but I'm sure someone has.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay- thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By the way, can I ask you something about being a web developer? I was wondering, I know that web developers have to know html, css and JS, but do they sort of specialize in doing particular aspects only, or do they have to be able to know and do everything? I am asking because, while I can do responsive design, I keep seeing new ways of doing it appearing, and I haven't learned all of them, and I have this anxiety and fear of working as a dev, and not knowing something. Is it normal if web devs sort of focus on certain stuff only, or do they have to be experts at everything?

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to ask, I've generally worked in quite small teams where we all have to do a little bit of everything. I think the largest web team I was ever on was about 15 people, and on that project we did have one guy who did most of the HTML+CSS (because he was the designer and tinkered until it looked the way he wanted it), but we still had to lots when doing the implementatinos. But that is not the only way things are done in the industry. I understand sometimes things are very thoroughly delineated, I just haven't happened to work in those environments.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see. Okay, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try to user ownerNode attribute to change title:

```
document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode.setAttribute('title', 'newtitle');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/ownerNode

Comment: It works. But why does it not work the other way? And what is the connection between the `link` element and the `stylesheets` object?

Comment: Also, why is it that, when I target the `link` element, and I disable one of the stylesheets via the `link` element, then using the `link` element length, it tells me that there are the same number of stylesheets, but using the `stylesheets` object, it tells me that the disabled one is one gone, and there are 1 less stylesheets left. How come?